# JetBrains WebStorm npm modules autocompletion not working

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am new to Node.js development and I have installed WebStorm from JetBrains to use it as my JavaScript IDE.

So I am following a tutorial in Udemy and I have come to notice the following problem.

I installed some modules with npm from WebStorm Console and although my JS script is working as intended, WebStorm autocompletion for the npm modules is not working.

Coding assistance for Node.js in my settings is marked! What do I do wrong?

[image: Image Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems occur because of the weird way properties are defined. 
For example, in `chalk` package they are generated dynamically using `Object.defineProperty(this, styleName, {value: builder});`, where the `styleName` is a color name you use in your code. There is no way to resolve them when analyzing file statically.

Normally installing [Typescript stubs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files) can be used as a workaround. But this doesn't work for `validator` due to [WEB-43528](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43528). 
`chulk` typings are included in package distribution, but not resolved because the required fields in `package.json` are missing. As a workaround, open `node_modules/chalk/package.json` and add `"types": "index.d.ts",` to it:

[image]

this should help:

[image]